# Using negative values / unsigned integers to implement SHA-2

Tags: implementation, sha-256

What happens if we allow implementation of SHA-2 using negative values?

What happens if a negative value was used in the first round? Would the algorithm still result in a secure value?

I have a *basic* understanding of how the maths work. However, before I go writing my own function - could somebody indicate if they have any experience using negative values?

Comment: It's unclear what your asking. Do you mean what happens if the input is a negative value? Or if the constants in the compression function are negative? Negative input value is still just a sequence of bits, would be handled just fine. Changing the compression function would mean it's not SHA256 anymore.

Comment: @puzzleplace I'm not concerned with it being pure, functional SHA256, I'm trying to find ways to make it do unexpected things. So, what I was trying to ask was, when the input of any value in any round is switched to binary, what happens if it's a negative value? As far as I can tell, everything is always positive...maybe an easier way to ask would be...if all the IVs were negative at the start of the first round, does it change anything?  What? How?

Comment: Well SHA256 operates on binary input, for how to convert a negative number to binary take a look at [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), it's a common way used to represent negative numbers. The internals of SHA256 have no notion of "positive" or "negative", they're operating on purely binary data. The IV is also binary data, it can be convenient to represent them as 32 bit unsigned integers but they again have no real notion of "positive" or "negative".

Comment: @puzzleplace So, if a value is negative, when it gets converted to binary, it will have the same value as it would if it had been positive to start?

Comment: (I may have inadvertently asked a question I am not smart enough to understand the answer too...)

Comment: Simply put: SHA takes bits as input, not numbers. Therefore, if you have a negative number that you want hashed then it's up to you how you'd like to represent that number as bits (e.g. how to encode it).  By leaving encoding up to the user and specifying the domain (input) in bits the SHA algorithm is agnostic to what your bits represent, be it negative numbers, emojis, text, pictures, vote tallys, etc.

Comment: @Thomas M. DuBuisson Appreciated, but I am trying to figure out something else.  I may be asking an impossible question.  Maybe the idea of "negative bits" is nonsense, but that's what I'm trying to accomplish.  Thanks for taking time to reply, but I'm thinking the real answer is "you can't do that, because science/math."

Comment: Yes, nonsense. Bits are either 1 or 0. SHA inputs are bitvectors like `1001111010`.  Asking for a SHA hash of anything else is nonsense.

Comment: Java implementations **must** be implemented as signed numbers as even bytes are considered signed (a huge design mistake if you ask me, but there we are). So any open source implementation in Java such as the one in the JDK itself, Bouncy Castle, IAIK etc. etc. could serve as an example on how to use signed values. Note that Java also hasn't got a rotate function (for instance) which may muddle the implementation more.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't see any reason to close this question. If you must you could flag it but generally I would just let it sit here. If this is your first implementation of a cryptographic primitive then this is a perfectly fine question to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 32-bit values in SHA-256 are unsigned integers, which means the only values they are allowed to have are between 0 and 4,294,967,295, there are no negative values allowed.

If you look at the 4th initial value (0xa54ff53a), that has an integer value of 2,773,480,762. Implementing SHA-256 in programming languages that do not have the a 32-bit unsigned integer, but rather a signed integer, results in that value being interpreted as -1,521,486,534, but the bits of the value are still the same.

For modular addition that is not an issue, (see two's complement), but can be an issue for the shifting and rotations, which need to be performed across all 32-bits, and not just the lower 31. XOR also does not care if the numbers are signed are not, and since SHA-2 only uses addition, XOR, and shifting (and thus rotation), implementing SHA-256 in a programming language that only supports unsigned integers is possible, just maybe a little slower if you have to deal with rotation through shifting of a signed integer, like in Visual Basic 6.

Comment: I program in VB6 as a hobby, and my SHA-256 implementation is the fastest one that exists as far as I am aware

Comment: VB6 is My favorite language.  It was the first one I learned, and as far as I know is still the best option for writing something you need to work on multiple versions of M$ Windows, without having to figure out a bunch of .NET nonsense.